# Error in YAML while scanning a simple key at line 17, column 5 could not find expected ':' at line 22, column 1

Tags: r, yaml

I am trying to use `rmarkdown::render_site()` in order to build a website.
Whenever I run the Build Website in R, an error appears like this..

> Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) :
> Scanner error: while scanning a simple key at line 17, column 5 could not find expected ':' at line 22, column 1
> Calls:  ... default_site -> site_config -> yaml_load -> 
> Execution halted

### My codes are

````
title: "Who is into Green Infrastructure"
author: Sun 
subtititle: Motivation of Green Infrastructure Parcipation
---

# Introduction

 Due to global warming, one of the difficulties that the urban
environment face is the increase of precipitation. There is a chance
that this will lead to water pollution as the stormwater that runs
through the urban impervious surface collects pollutants and enters the
sewer system. There has been continuous effort to implement green
infrastructure to adapt to this environmental change. However there are
certain limits because this involves the voluntary participation of
individual households. This study will help understand the motivation of the participants of the past rain barrel project and help guide environmental organizations to plan how to increase participation.
This project will analyze the motivation of households participating in the rain barrel project by comparing contributing factors which are the education attainment and median income at the census tract level. The education attainment and income of the people participating in this project will be represented as a map. Then the shapefile of the rain barrels will be overlapped in order to analyze the demographic characteristic of households participating in the project. 


# Materials and methods

```
{r}
1+2
```
````

Comment: you are missing ``` at the end you posted. You r chunked is not closed.

Comment: I think perhaps you are missing the top `---` at the start of the YAML. Should be first line of code.